# estimating standard error for small sample sizes

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error

I have generated a number of objects in 3D space (2D rectangles). I have sampled those objects along lines, calculating the number of intersections between the lines and objects.

If I use increasing amounts of lines, the standard error in the number of intersections decreases, as expected.

What I really want to know is: How many sampling lines do I need to use to get a good idea of the # of objects (or intersections).

I have plotted a line graph of the mean number of intersections per line vs the number of sampling lines, along with the +/- 95% confidence interval for the mean number of intersections per line.

At high numbers of lines, the graph looks good and stable. But, at low numbers of intersection lines, the graph is erratic and somewhat unstable due to the smaller sample size.

How could I do a better job of calculating the mean and confidence interval for small sample sizes? Or maybe, can/should I analytically derive the number of intersections and confidence interval? Not sure how I would do that.[image: My Chart]

Comment: The devil lies in defining things like your phrase "*to get a good idea of*"

Comment: The variability in the estimate scales inversely with the square root of the number of observations. More observations give less variability in the estimate. You need to decide how many observations are worthwhile on the basis of how much they cost and how much the mis-estimation is worth.

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is just the strong law of large numbers. Small samples are almost surely more erratic than larger samples (assuming iid values, of course). For example, if you are sampling from a normal population of unknown mean and variance, then the confidence intervals and t-statistics will be more erratic for smaller sample sizes.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's something I can't get around. It's just really annoying for this analysis. Thanks for your input.